# Spark - use dataframe many times without many unloads

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I got question. How I can copy dataframe without unload it again to redshift ?

```
val companiesData = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
.option("url","jdbc:redshift://xxxx:5439/cf?user="+user+"&password="+password)
.option("query","select * from cf_core.company")
//.option("dbtable",schema+"."+table)
.option("aws_iam_role","arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/somerole")
.option("tempdir","s3a://xxxxx/Spark")
.load()

import class.companiesData
class test {
val secondDF = filteredDF(companiesData)

 def filteredDF(df: Dataframe): Dataframe {
   val result = df.select("companynumber")
  result
 }
}
```

In this case this will unload data twice. First select * from table and second it will unload by select only companynumber. How I can unload data once and operate on this many times ? This is serious problem for me. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

By "unload", do you mean read the data? If so, why are you sure it's being read twice? In fact, you don't have any action in your code, so I'm not even sure if the data is being read at all. If you do try to access secondDF somewhere else in the code, spark *should* only read the column you select in your class 'test'. I'm not 100% sure of this because I've never used redshift to load data into spark before.

In general, if you want to reuse a dataframe, you should cache it using

```
companiesData.cache()
```

Then, whenever you call an action on the dataframe, it will be cached into memory.